# Objects are not valid as a React Child (found: object with keys{id, name})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, radio-button

im trying to implement radio buttons into my react native project with a callback from the component

Im using **react-native-radio-buttons** *SegmentedControls* into the project

**App.js**

```
import files....
import RadioButtons from "../components/RadioButtons";

//Data
const PackingType = [{id:"1", name: "Bag"},{id: "2",name: "Box"}];

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      packTypeSelected: [],
    };
  }
...

  renderAddPackType(selectedOption, selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex });
    console.log(selectedIndex[0]);
  }

...
render(){
return(
...

 <RadioButtons
            buttonOptions={PackingType}
            callback={this.renderAddPackType.bind(this)}
            selectedOption={"Bag"}
          />

...
)
}
```

**RadioButtons.js**

```
import { SegmentedControls } from "react-native-radio-buttons";
export default class RadioButtons extends Component {
  onSelectedItemsChange = (selectedOption, selectedIndex) => {
    this.props.callback(selectedOption, selectedIndex);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 20, marginVertical: 10 }}>
        <SegmentedControls
          options={this.props.buttonOptions}
          onSelection={(selectedOption, selectedIndex) =>
            this.onSelectedItemsChange(selectedOption, selectedIndex)
          }
          selectedOption={this.props.selectedOption}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
 Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

im not much experienced in development so far..
kindly help with the mistakes done here

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was reading the documentation from `react-native-radio-buttons` and just found out that

> You can also specify how to extract the labels from the options through the extractText prop

Which is clearly missing from your code. Here is what they expect you to do

```
  <SegmentedControls
    options={this.props.buttonOptions}
    onSelection={(selectedOption, selectedIndex) =>
      this.onSelectedItemsChange(selectedOption, selectedIndex)
    }
    selectedOption={this.props.selectedOption}
    extractText={ (option) => option.name }
    testOptionEqual={(selectedValue, option) => selectedValue === option.name}
  />
```

I haven't tried it but I think it would work

Comment: i have tried this, it removes error but, selected value is undefined

Comment: `renderAddPackType(selectedOption, selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({ packTypeSelected: selectedOption.name });
    console.log(selectedOption);
  }
`
this solved the issue but the selection is getting some delayed after press in some millisec

Comment: Ah, good catch! What if you just use the callback method directly instead of using that proxy method `onSelectedItemsChange`.

Comment: can you please expand the sentence sir,

Comment: and also how can i set initial values i.e default values

Comment: `onSelection={(selectedOption, selectedIndex) =>this.props.callback(selectedOption, selectedIndex)}`
yea i understood this point 
Thank you
One more small help sir, 
how can i set up default values

Comment: What do you mean by set up default values? You already have specified the value that you wanted to be selected with `selectedOption` in `RadioButtons`. 
Also, please make sure to up vote the answer too if I was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, `SegmentedControls` attribute `options` accept a `ReactNode`, and you assigning an array `Object`.

Change the `PackingType` type to `ReactElement`, for example:

```
// Array Object - throws an error
const PackingType = [{id:"1", name: "Bag"},{id: "2",name: "Box"}];

// ReactNode example
const PackingType = (
  <div>
    {[{ id: "1", name: "Bag" }, { id: "2", name: "Box" }].map(type => (
      <div key={type.id}>{type.name}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

// Assigning as props
<RadioButtons
  buttonOptions={PackingType}
  callback={this.renderAddPackType.bind(this)}
  selectedOption={"Bag"}
/>

// Using them inside SegmentedControls
<View>
  <SegmentedControls
    options={this.props.buttonOptions}
  />
</View>
```

Note that I didn't check what `SegmentedControls` accepts in options attribute, it may be array of `ReactNode`s or something else, just recheck it because you assigning the wrong type.

Comment: Sir, im not using react js, sorry for the tag.. instead of div component what should i go with ?

Comment: I think it's just `View` in react-native

Comment: sir, later i will be getting data from server, i could not find it as appropriate.. any other possibility to make a clean code